# Transactions with ASP.net WEB API

Tags: .net, transactions, asp.net-web-api

I understand that ASP.NET WEB API has been built to help implement lightweight REST based applications. However, i need my REST services to be transactional/be part of a transaction. I tried looking around, but it looks like there is no way to enlist WEB APIs as part of a client initiated transaction. Is there a way to do this?

regards
Jagadish

Comment: What do you consider a transaction? A generic unit of work? A `DbTransaction` or a `SqlTransaction`?

Comment: I was looking at having transaction managed by DTC, but it looks like WEB API doesnt support it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are referring to distributed transactions (via MSDTC) which can propagate over service boundaries.

However, distributed transactions over WCF RESTful services are not possible because there is simply no way to propagate and manage the transaction state over plain HTTP requests.

You may want to look into plain WCF services, over HTTP (wsHttpBinding) or TCP/IP (net.tcp), or even give a look on [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792.aspx).

Answer (score 12):

If you control both ends of the wire, it's possible to achieve what you want.

The [TransactionInterop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactioninterop%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class exists to provide support for working with transactions between process boundaries, leveraging MS DTC.

It contains two methods which are interesting to your scenario:

- [`GetTransmitterPropagationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactioninterop.gettransmitterpropagationtoken(v=vs.100).aspx) - This gets a token which can be used to propagate the transaction outside of the current process.
- [`GetTransactionFromTransmitterPropagationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactioninterop.gettransactionfromtransmitterpropagationtoken(v=vs.100).aspx) - This takes a propagation token and uses it to construct the transaction in the local service.

You can use the first method in your client to generate a transaction. You can set it as a custom header value or a cookie to pass it to your service. Once on the service, you can use the second method to create the transaction locally.

The major caveat to this is that MS DTC will need to be enabled and configured at client and server. This is only really achievable if your services are being invoked within a Windows Active Directory Domain.

Comment: A slightly more in-depth article about this: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Distributed-Transactions-c7e0a8c2

Answer (score 4):

Enlisting service calls in transactions is generally thought of as a SOAP behaviour not a REST behaviour. At least there is a standardised way of doing it with SOAP called WS-AtomicTransaction.

Being SOAP oriented, this is not explicitly supported by the ASP.Net Web API, but it is supported by WCF

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730266

It would be possible to implement similar a similar behaviour yourself in REST, but it is relatively complex to do reliably.

Comment: "but it is relatively complex to do reliably." - any thoughts on what the approach would be if we wanted to implement it?

Answer (score 2):

**Distributed transaction with WEB API (across Application Domains)**

In order to have my ASP.NET WEB API transnational or part of a transaction (via MSDTC to propagate over service boundaries), I implemented an 
Web API's Action Filter that retrieves the **transaction token sent by client request** and use it to **enroll a service transaction in the same client scope transaction**.

This filter can be simply applied to the Web API action as:

```
[HttpPost] 
[EnlistToDistributedTransactionActionFilter] 
public HttpResponseMessage Post(string id) 
{
   ...
}
```

Client application just must open the transaction and pass it in the request:

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope()) 
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
    { 
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://acme.com/api/order", id))) 
        { 
            // extension method that forward transaction token to Web API
            request.AddTransactionPropagationToken(); 
            var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result; 
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode(); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Mode details, example and source code, can be found here: 
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/distributed-transactions-with-webapi-across-application-domains/